# How to correct error of floating point modulo operation

Tags: shader, cg

Some mobile GPU doesn't support integral modulo operation. So I have to implement modulo operation using floating-point precision.
Implementation of fmod in Cg standard library is as follows.

```
float2 fmod(float2 a, float2 b)
{
  float2 c = frac(abs(a/b))*abs(b);
  return (a < 0) ? -c : c;   /* if ( a < 0 ) c = 0-c */
}
```

And usually "a/b" is calculated as "a * rcp( b )".
In some cases fmod returns unexpected value because of floating-point error (for instance, when a == b). Is there light-weight way to overcome the error? One idea is adding a bias like fmod(a + bias, b) where 0.0 < bias < 1.0. But it's not robust. Any comment or pointer to reference is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.